# what's the difference with the usage of thest two bitblt?

Tags: winapi, mfc

read the code below:
 why **m_dcMem.BitBlt(0,0,m_size.cx, m_size.cy, &dcScreen, 0,0, SRCCOPY);**  works ,
 and **dcScreen.BitBlt(0,0,m_size.cx, m_size.cy, &m_dcMem, 0,0, SRCCOPY);** don't?
THX!
`

int CScreenDlg::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)

```
if (CDialog::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
    return -1;
// TODO:  Add your specialized creation code here   
ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);

CDC dcScreen;
dcScreen.CreateDC("DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);
//dcScreen.Attach(GetDC(GetParent()));
m_size.cx = GetDeviceCaps(dcScreen.GetSafeHdc(), HORZRES);
m_size.cy = GetDeviceCaps(dcScreen.GetSafeHdc(), VERTRES);

m_dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC(&dcScreen);
m_bmpScreen.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dcScreen, m_size.cx,m_size.cy);
CBitmap* pOldBmp = m_dcMem.SelectObject(&m_bmpScreen);
//m_dcMem.BitBlt(0,0,m_size.cx, m_size.cy, &dcScreen, 0,0, SRCCOPY);
dcScreen.BitBlt(0,0,m_size.cx, m_size.cy, &m_dcMem, 0,0, SRCCOPY); //why it doesn't work???
CRect rect(0,0,m_size.cx, m_size.cy);

LEFT_RECT = CRect(INFO_OFFSET, INFO_OFFSET, INFO_OFFSET + INFO_WIDTH, INFO_OFFSET + INFO_HEIGHT);
RIGHT_RECT = CRect(m_size.cx - INFO_WIDTH-INFO_OFFSET, INFO_OFFSET, m_size.cx-INFO_OFFSET, INFO_OFFSET + INFO_HEIGHT);
m_rectInfo = LEFT_RECT;

m_bmpInfoBK.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP_INFOBK);
MoveWindow(rect);
ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
m_hCursor = LoadCursor(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CURSOR_SELECT));
return 0;
```

}

Comment: The one that *works* is slamming bits from the screen DC to the memory DC. the one that doesn't is attempting to slam bits from an unpopulated bitmap in the memory DC back to the screen. When in doubt, btw, check your return codes, including GLE.

Comment: Please clarify what you expect the code to do.  Are you trying to display an image or capture the screen?

Comment: Yeah,capture the screen!  and what's the difference?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? What happens?